# How to remove entries from Google Cloud Datastore index?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I manually removed all data from Google Cloud Datastore using delete button on https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query. However, when I checked indexes they are still remaining and there is no delete button on https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes. I tried to use console command

```
gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes
```

But this command does not help.

Are there any way to clean the indexes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find more details on how the workflow of Datastore indexes should work on the documentation. Specifically, there is an entry explaining [how to delete unused indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Deleting_unused_indexes) and a summary of [the workflow of indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/#the_development_workflow_using_the_command-line_tool).

In short, in order to force the deletion of indexes (because they are not automatically deleted by default, as they are kept for some time to ensure that performance is not affected), you will first have to update your local `index.yaml` file, deleting the indexes that you no longer need. Then, you can use the command you shared pointing to the local file, and your indexes should disappear:

```
gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes /path/to/file/index.yaml
```

Answer (score 7):

`gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes /path/to/file/index.yaml`

this command **no longer works**.

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup /path/to/index.yaml`

this is the **new command**.

you should run them in `google cloud console`. normally you can upload the `index.yaml` file using `file upload` feature in `google cloud console`. your file goes to a directly called `_admin` you can `cd` to there and call,

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml`

#### Tip

if you are using `datastore` in a **java project**, you have `datastore-indexes.xml` instead of `index.yaml`. You might have some trouble finding the `index.yaml` file if you don't know where to look.

you can simply find the path of the `index.yaml` file by looking at the `deploy console` in your IDE.

Comment: Documentation of deprecated xml file is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig